# Lake Formation - Compaction Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

Recently started using Lake Formation in AWS. Testing out the compaction feature specifically. I see files are being consolidated in s3 (run-*.parquet), however on the console it mentions "Compaction Failed" with warning message "Optimizer was unable to create log stream in your account. Please double check the permissions with this Table." What are the steps needed to resolve this? The documentation did not list out this particular error in troubleshooting.

Wasn't sure where to go in order to resolve the above error, hoping others have encountered and resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: default permissions on my account did not have a policy for CreateLogStream. Created a policy for that, gave LakeFormation access to it and problem solved.